# Vue cannot register coponent if JS file is loaded externally

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I'm using vue in regular js files (not .vue) and inline templates. I got few components that are loaded depend on the subpage. What I wanted to do is to load some global vue variables and vue coponents and then dynamically, using jQuery load additional vue coponents script if some container (eg. #blog) has lenght > 0.

The issue is that Vue is throwing an error that it found the Vue tags but couldn't register the component.

Is there any way of loading dynamically the JS files? I got really big website with a lot of js files that I want to load only on specific subpages. It works perfectly for all jQuery libs but sadly not for Vue components.

Example component below:

```
Vue.component('blog-entries', {
    name: "blog-entries",
    template: require('js/vue/home/blog/blog.html').template,
    data: function () {
        return {
            blog_entries: [

            ]
        }
    }
});
```

and error:

> [Vue warn]: Unknown custom element:  - did you register
>   the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to
>   provide the "name" option.
>
> (found in )

load script:

```
function loadScript(scriptName, callback) {

    if (!_arr[scriptName]) {
        _arr[scriptName] = true;

        var body        = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
        var script      = document.createElement('script');
        script.type     = 'text/javascript';
        script.src      = scriptName;

        // then bind the event to the callback function
        // there are several events for cross browser compatibility
        // script.onreadystatechange = callback;
        script.onload = callback;

        // fire the loading
        body.appendChild(script);

    } else if (callback) {

        callback();

    }

};
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var vapp = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: function() {
    return {
      componentName: ''
    }
  },
  computed: {
    currentComponent: function() {
      var vm = this;
      if (!vm.componentName) return;

      if (!vm.$options.components[vm.componentName] //if not registered locally
          && !Vue.options.components[vm.componentName]) {//nor globally yet

        //load the component async'ly
        Vue.component(vm.componentName, function(resolve) {
          //adjust the path to where your component files are
          var filePath = 'https://elfan.net/vue-components/' + vm.componentName + '.vue.js';
          loadScript(filePath, resolve);
        });
      }
      return vm.componentName;
    }
  }
});

/*below is your own third party script loader*/
var _arr = {};
function loadScript(scriptName, callback) {

    if (!_arr[scriptName]) {
        _arr[scriptName] = true;

        var body        = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
        var script      = document.createElement('script');
        script.type     = 'text/javascript';
        script.src      = scriptName;

        // then bind the event to the callback function
        // there are several events for cross browser compatibility
        // script.onreadystatechange = callback;
        script.onload = callback;

        // fire the loading
        body.appendChild(script);

    } else if (callback) {

        callback();

    }

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>

    <div id="app">
      <input v-model="componentName">
      <div :is="currentComponent"></div>
    </div>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.4.2/vue.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>

  </body>

</html>
```

In the main app (the one which loads the subpage), try something like this:

```
Vue.component('blog-entries', function(resolve) {
    loadScript('blog-entries.js', resolve);
})
```

where 'blog-entries' should be the same as your Vue component's name and 'blog-entries.js' is the js file containing your Vue component that you want to load dynamically.

Edit: to follow up, here I put the complete code for loading vue components dynamically. The component will be loaded and rendered immediately on user typing.
You can try typing "ant", "bird" or "cat". I have placed vue components with those names on my server.

Comment: is there any other way just to require the whole `blog-entries` js file if those tags will be available?

Comment: Do you mean that the component name is not known beforehand? Yes, it can load any component name dynamically, not just the ones that are hard-coded. I have edited my answer by adding the complete demo code above.